# Template syntax error Could not parse the remainder: '("images/logo.png")' from 'static("images/logo.png")'. in django-jinja template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, jinja2

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="icon" href="{{ static 'images/logo.png' }}"  alt="Company Logo">

     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" 
     crossorigin="anonymous">

     <title>Hello, world!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

     <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
  </body>
</html>
```

When including the static files in the Django-jinja template it shows an error below:

> Template syntax error Could not parse the remainder: '("images/logo.png")' from 'static("images/logo.png")'

If I removed that line It worked. But I want to load my static files in jinja template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to load static at top of your **html** page

```
{% load static %}
```

Then you have to use `{% %}` instead of `{{ }}`

```
<link rel="icon" href="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"  alt="Company Logo">
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. but I thought the load tag is not working in the jinja template. so that I mentioned the href="{{ static 'images/logo.png'  }}".

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `{% load static %}` first

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error below:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ':upper' from '"Hello":upper'

Because I used `:` in [upper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#upper) filter as shown below

```
       {% ↓ %}
{{ "Hello":upper }}
```

So, I used `|` in `upper` filter as shown below, then the error was solved:

```
       {% ↓ %}
{{ "Hello"|upper }}
```